# Why are my, ungrouped & top of artboard layer, objects invisible when moved into a sketch artboard?

Tags: sketch-app, artboard

**Visible outside of artboard:**

[image]

*layers outside of artboard*

[image]

**Invisible inside of artboard:**

[image]

*top of layer stack*

[image]

Comment: I'm not a SketchApp user but use other vector software. Looks to me like there's something covering it. Check your other layers. Move the graphics layers to a position above those other layers.

Comment: There's nothing above these layers at all, they're definitely on top of everything (according to the layers sidebar). I place them from outside of the Artboard on to the Artboard, but the layers just seem to get hidden behind the artboard. V frustrating. Other elements are visible on the artboard, as you see from the 1st pic above.

Comment: Again this is only a guess, and I can't test it, but maybe try it another way, like cut (Command+X), then select your artboard, and then paste (Command+V).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @BillyKerr, but no joy, copy paste still renders the elements invisible. I've checked opacities in case anything weird going on there, nope, just something to do with layers or masks that I can't work out.

Comment: When I find seemingly unsolvable problems involving layers, sometimes I try copying and pasting the contents to a new document, just in case it's a document specific problem. Maybe try that, and you might be able to find the problem by a process of trial and error, and elimination.  Good luck anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The arrow symbol next to your layers are an indicator that there is an underlying mask somewhere. If you scroll all the way down to the last one of your new layers – Oval Copy 5(?) – the layer below that should have the "Mask" option selected. If you disable this mask it should not be invisible anymore.